# What determines the electron affinity of a molecule?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, charge

I was reading about how materials get charged by friction. In [this resource](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/estatics/Lesson-2/Charging-by-Friction) it is stated that

> The triboelectric charging process (a.k.a., charging by friction) results in a transfer of electrons between the two objects that are rubbed together. Rubber has a much greater attraction for electrons than animal fur. As a result, the atoms of rubber pull electrons from the atoms of animal fur, leaving both objects with an imbalance of charge.

I understand most parts of the explanation above, but I still don't understand exactly why some materials have a greater attraction to electrons than others. In the same text, it is stated earlier that

> Simply put, the property of electron affinity refers to the relative amount of love that a material has for electrons.

And as I understand it, my question then becomes "What determines the electron affinity of a molecule?"

I think the answer has to do with the [polarizability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizability) of different materials which, if I understand correctly, is determined by the innate chemical structure of the molecules of said material. I'm not sure if my intuition is correct or if there are other things that determine when a material tends to attract electrons or not. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!